# Spring mvc rewrite url "myapp.com/Foo/12345/test-one" to "myapp.com/Foo/12345/test-one-a-b"

Tags: java, spring, url, spring-mvc

I want to use a normal spring mvc controler and request mapping using path variables.

I do not want to forward or redirect, just change the string that user sees.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/Foo/{id}/*", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView getFoo(@PathVariable final String friendlyUrl) {
//how can I rewite the url that user sees ?
}
```

**(the same behaviour as when you change the title of an existing question on stackoverflow)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you watch the traffic in wireshark, firebug or something you see, that stackoverflow sends a HTTP 301 Moved Permanently to the final URL.
You could do the same.

For this you need the `HttpServletResponse`, you can add it to the method signature to get it injected.
Set the permanent redirect:

```
String rightUrl = urlCompleter.complete(friendlyUrl);
response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_MOVED_PERMANENTLY);
response.setHeader("Location", rightUrl);
```

Where you need to implement `urlCompleter` on your own, eg. look in the database table of entries and locate the right url component.

Comment: yeah that helps, with spring mvc I can use a RedirectView, but I am still not sure how to access the original url

Comment: oh yes, the right url you have to lookup on your own strategy, in some kind of database or something,..(like here, the stackoverflow question table..)

Comment: and be sure to send permanent redirects, not temporary ones, this is the right semantic.